# How to generate a drill down data from highcharts table?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates

I am new to front end development and using django to build a dashboard. I am leveraging high charts library for data visualization.
I want to create a click event table with drill down data of point triggered.
I want to send the click point details back to my views and trigger the view function (with view points as variables) to generate the table in a new page.
Please suggest what functionalities can i use to achieve this?
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Eg. If user clicks on first bar, he should be directed to a new webpage which will have detailed tabular data fetched from database of Q1 2019.

Check the jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/VM001/90jpvdw3/2/

```
point:{
     events:{
         click: function () {
             location.href ="clickTable";
             alert('Category:'+this.category+',values:'+this.y)
             alert(this.series.name)
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think that your question now is not related to using the Highcharts library because from the Highcharts site nothing more could be done - you need to create your own logic inside the `click function`.

Comment: yes...can you suggest how can i pass the values from templates/JS to views???  I added the JSfiddle just for some clarity on the question.

Comment: I don't know django and I am afraid that I not will be able to help you with that. I am here because of the `Highcharts` tag.